# How to make mongoose fail if field is not in schema?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want mongoose fails if I try to save document with field which is not in schema.

I know about `strict` option (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict), but it does not cover my needs. `strict: true` removes fields without warning. And `strict: false` allows to save everything (which is not good in long terms).

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { /* ?? */ })
var Thing = mongoose.model('Thing', thingSchema);
var thing = new Thing({ iAmNotInTheSchema: true });
thing.save();
```

Is there a way to provide some option so `thing.save();` fails with error?

I'd like to turn this option on for local development. This way I can find typos and forgotten fields without hard debugging

---

**Update to answer**:

*Following is true for mongoose `v5.3.14`. They may change it in future versions.*

Keep in mind that `"strict": "throw"` does not cover all situations. Most of create/update operation will throw:

```
const model = new Model({ name: 'Mario', iAmNotInTheSchema: true })
await Model.create({ name: 'Mario', iAmNotInTheSchema: true })
await Model.updateOne({}, { iAmNotInTheSchema: true })
await Model.updateMany({}, { iAmNotInTheSchema: true })
await Model.findOneAndUpdate({}, { iAmNotInTheSchema: true })
await Model.findOneAndUpdate({}, { $set: { iAmNotInTheSchema: true } })
```

Error message is nice:

```
Field `iAmNotInTheSchema` is not in schema and strict mode is set to throw.
```

But for this case:

```
const model = await Model.findOne({})
model.iAmNotInTheSchema = true
await model.save()
```

it will not throw. The code runs without any errors, and iAmNotInTheSchema will be ignored (like with `strict: true`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The strict option may also be set to "throw" which will cause errors to be produced instead of dropping the bad data.

There is an option passed to the schema constructor to throw errors on such conditions. Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

```
new Schema({..}, {"strict": "throw"});
```

Comment: According https://stackoverflow.com/a/41419546/1142300 it should not work. But let me try it by myself first

Comment: @DenisZavershinskiy I have not tried it myself. Did you get a chance to check?

Comment: Yes, I've played with it and found that it mostly works. I have added details to your answer.